# Helping sketching a set in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need help sketching the following sets in $\mathbb{C}$. $$A= \lbrace z\in\mathbb{C}:  \left|\frac{z+i}{z-3i}\right|  \le 1 \rbrace$$

$$B=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z-i| \le Im(z) \}$$

$$C= \{z \in \mathbb{C}: | Arg(z+1)| < \frac{\pi}{4} \}$$

I'm brushing up on my complex analysis and I don't recall sketching these and there are no examples on my introductory complex analysis book. I'm trying to convert $z=x+iy$ and playing around with it but I don't recognize anything geometrically. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For A you get $|z+i| \le |z-3i|$, i.e. the distance from $z$ to $-i$ should be no larger than the distance from $z$ to $3i$. Try to argue geometrically which points are closer to $-i$ than to $3i$.

For B we have that the distance from $z$ to $i$ should be smaller than the distance from $z$ to the real axis. Either argue geometrically (this is harder than A) or put $z=x+iy$, square and do some algebra.

For C, first think about the easier set $\{ -\frac \pi4 < \operatorname{Arg}(z) < \frac\pi4 \}$.

Comment: I'm getting $y \le 1$ for A. Am I on the right track? If so then I know what to do for the rest.

Comment: @User69127 that sounds right

Comment: What about for something like $Re(e^z) \le 0 $

Comment: That looks like a completely new question.. but $e^{z} = e^x\cos y + i e^x\sin y$. So: when is $e^x \cos y \le 0$?

Comment: Thought I'd ask the professor since we're talking about sketching already. Yes I got the $e^xcosy \le 0$. I'm trying to make geometric sense out of this. e^x is never less than or equal to zero. But cos y is. So $y=\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi, \frac{3 \pi}{2}$

Comment: Do we just ignore $e^x$ and focus on $cos y$?

Answer (score 2):

For the first part, there is a nice fact. If we have $$z=\frac{z_1}{z_2}=\frac{x_1+iy_1}{x_2+iy_2}$$ then with a boring handy calculations we get: $$z=\left(\frac{x_1x_2+y_1y_2}{x_2^2+y_2^2}\right)+i\left(\frac{y_1x_2-y_2x_1}{x_2^2+y_2^2}\right)$$ Here, we, then, want to find out what is: $$\left|\frac{x^2+(y+1)(y-3)}{x^2+(y-3)^2}+\frac{4x}{x^2+(y-3)^2}i\right|\leq 1$$ According to $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, so we get $$\frac{x^2+1+y^2+2y}{x^2+y^2-6y+9}\leq1\iff y\leq 1$$

Comment: I did it slightly different but ended up getting the same result as you did. For part C, does $Arg(z+1)$ become $tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x+1})$ ?

Comment: I'm getting a line $y\lt x+1$ not sure if I'm correct

Comment: Hope it gets back up and running. My assumption is that the +1 is shifting the $tan^{-1}( \frac{y}{x+1})$ to the left 1 and the angle parallel to the x axis will be $\frac {\pi}{4}$